# Updating MDB records with Excel 16 - ActiveX component can't create object

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have an Excel VBA macro that would update an MDB record's specific field value in 2010.

I just got updated to Excel16 and I am getting an ActiveX component can't create object error with the once functional code.

it errors on `Set Db = OpenDatabase(MDBPath)`

here is the full code:

```
Sub UpdateAccess()

MDBPath = Sheets("Setup").Range("E19").Value
TabName = Sheets("Setup").Range("E20").Value

Set Db = OpenDatabase(MDBPath)
Set rs = Db.OpenRecordset(TabName, dbOpenTable)

With Sheets("Batches")
    lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

BatchNameColumn = Sheets("references").Range("G22").Value
BatchDEColumn = Sheets("references").Range("G28").Value

i = 1

Do While i < lRow

    i = i + 1

    BatchName = Sheets("BatchesForLabels").Range(BatchNameColumn & i).Value

    With rs
        rs.MoveFirst
        While Not rs.EOF
            If rs.Fields("Name").Value = BatchName Then
                rs.Edit
                rs.Fields("ActualDE").Value = Round(Sheets("BatchesForLabels").Range(BatchDEColumn & i).Value, 2)
                rs.Update
                rs.MoveNext
            Else:
                rs.MoveNext
            End If
        Wend
    End With

Loop

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Db.Close
Set Db = Nothing
```

here are the references I have enabled

```
Visual Basic For Applications
Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library
OLE Automation
Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library
Microsoft ADO Ext. 2.8 for DDL and Security
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library
Microsoft Windows Common Controls - 26.0 (sp6)
Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library
```

Is this a reference library issue or is there a different strategy I need to approach updating MDB records in this new environment?

It is a workplace application and I can't exactly control various installation pieces at this time

Comment: `OpenDatabase` should be period qualified with a [Workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/workspace-opendatabase-method-dao) object. Where are your `Dim` statements?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub UpdateAccess()

    Dim oConn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim sConn As String
    Dim s As String

    MDBPath = Sheets("Setup").Range("E19").Value
    TabName = Sheets("Setup").Range("E20").Value

    s = MDBPath
    sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & s 'Access 2010

    Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    oConn.Open sConn

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    rs.Open TabName, oConn, 1, 3, &H2

    With Sheets("Batches")
        lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    BatchNameColumn = Sheets("references").Range("G22").Value
    BatchDEColumn = Sheets("references").Range("G28").Value

    i = 1

    Do While i < lRow

        i = i + 1

        BatchName = Sheets("BatchesForLabels").Range(BatchNameColumn & i).Value

        With rs
            rs.MoveFirst
            While Not rs.EOF
                If rs.Fields("Name").Value = BatchName Then
                    'rs.Edit
                    rs.Fields("ActualDE").Value = Round(Sheets("BatchesForLabels").Range(BatchDEColumn & i).Value, 2)
                    rs.Update
                    rs.MoveNext
                Else:
                    rs.MoveNext
                End If
            Wend
        End With

    Loop

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    oConn.Close
    Set oConn = Nothing
End Sub
```

added dim statements and changed to oledb 12.0. this code works for my purposes. had to take out rs.edit for anyone referencing this in the future

Comment: While this is the ADO method, the DAO should still be able to work.